# PHP multiple Isset declaration

Tags: php, html, forms, isset

I'm creating a PHP form for an RSVP, and I'm trying to declare multiple $_POST to 1 isset variable, but I keep getting errors in my code, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
    $attendance = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-event'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-event'] : '';

    $guestname1 = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-guestname1'], $_POST['template-contactform-guestname1r'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-guestname1'], $_POST['template-contactform-guestname1r'] : '';
```

So my error is occurring on the second declaration line $guestname1 I think its because of the second coma after the isset, but I'm not sure how I would declare this? The first line ($attendance) is what I'm trying to achieve but with two $_POST for 1 variable.

Comment: What is your error message? Also, try not to use ternary while debugging, you can always write a ternary afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While isset() can take multiple parameters, the inline iif() cannot.

Try this instead, I concatenated the two parameters.

```
<?php

$attendance = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-event'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-event'] : '';

$guestname1 = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-guestname1'], $_POST['template-contactform-guestname1r'] ) ? 
                $_POST['template-contactform-guestname1'].' '.$_POST['template-contactform-guestname1r'] : '';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked for me! Submitting this as answered as example was provided that works.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement is right.
But the second one has an error with the second comma.

If you take a look a the way ternary are supposed to be build:

`$val = my_test?result_if_true:result_if_false;`

You can do `isset( $_POST['template-contactform-guestname1'], $_POST['template-contactform-guestname1r'] )` because it will return a boolean.

But not write : `$_POST['template-contactform-guestname1'], $_POST['template-contactform-guestname1r']` has the second argument. Because ternary aren't expecting this comma.

If you want more informations I've found this article
https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: Thanks for this +!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning 2 values to one variable, that doesn't work, you will have to use an array.

And also isset() isn't the way to check if a user has inputted values to a form, because if a user submits a blank form then `isset($_POST['smth'])` will return true because the indexes are present in the superglobal `$_POST` and its value is set to empty string. Use `empty()` instead and an array to store 2 values.